# How do I evaluate the n'th order derivative of a variable-function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

This is what I am trying to do:

```
tmp[func_, arg_, order_] = Derivative[order][func][arg]
```

Which evaluates to:

$ func^{(order)}[x] $

This seems to be correct, but how can I get the software to evaluate the function at x?

```
tmp[3x+2, 1, 0]
```

produces

```
(2 + 3 x)[1]
```

and

```
f[x_] = 3x+2
```

`tmp[f[x], 1, 0]` produces the same thing

---

However, if I write the function explicitly,

```
f[x_] = 3x+2

tmp[arg_, order_] = Derivative[order][f][arg]
```

with

```
tmp[1, 0]
tmp[1, 1]
```

I get the expected output of `5` and `3`.

How do I need to define my tmp function so that `tmp[3x+2, 1, 0]` evaluates fully?

---

```
f[x_] = 2x+1

tmp[func_, arg_, order]

tmp[f, 2, 1]
```

This seems to work, but I still don't know how to define `tmp` in such a way as to allow me to pass in the function or write it within the call.

Comment: Your `func` needs to be a `Function` object. If you feed your `tmp` function with just `2 + 3 x`, it has no way of knowing what the variable is. Consider: what would happen if you put `2 y + 3 x` in it? Do you get `3` (the variable is `x`)? `2` (the variable is `y`) ? or `0` (the variable is something else)? [Here's the link to the documentation on `Function`.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)

Comment: Also, if you are making a function that changes value according to input, use [`SetDelayed (:=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). i.e. `tmp[func_, arg_, order_] := Derivative[order][func][arg]` and `f[x_] := 2x+1`. Just `Set (=)` will cause problems.

Comment: To add to the first comment, if `x` is already defined somewhere else, and it is not `Clear`ed, `2 + 3 x` would be evaluated and your derivative would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Clear[tmp];
tmp[func_, arg_, ord_, 
  argFix_] := (D[func, {arg, ord}] // Activate) /. arg -> argFix
```

Here `arg`is the argument of the function and `argFix` is its value that you want it to take after the derivative calculation.

Let us try:

```
    tmp[3 x + 2, x, 1, 1]
tmp[3 x + 2, x, 2, 1]

(*  3

0   *)
```

As it should be. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp[func_, arg_, order_] = Derivative[order][func][arg];
```

The `func` argument must be a [`pure function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) or the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of a defined function.

Either

```
tmp[3 # + 2 &, 1, 0]

(*  5  *)
```

or

```
tmp[Function[x, 3 x + 2], 1, 0]

(*  5  *)
```

or

```
Clear[f]

f = 3 # + 2 &;

tmp[f, 1, 0]

(*  5  *)
```

or

```
Clear[f]

f = Function[x, 3 x + 2];

tmp[f, 1, 0]

(*  5  *)
```

or as you observed.

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] = 3 x + 2;

tmp[f, 1, 0]

(*  5  *)
```